# Add one in Viewsate on click

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I want to have a label on my Quiz side that say what number of question it is like (2/7).

I use sql to save the questions, and the questions in one test share the same idtest but not the id. So that way i can get the last number. This is how the code look, but only get 1 on the first number it never change.

```
ViewState["questionNumberCounter"] = 1;
Session["questionid"] = 0;


  var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        var questionid = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            var cons = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
            using (var connection1 = new SqlConnection(cons))
            {
                connection1.Open();
                var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Question WHERE IdTest = @testId", connection1);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testId", id);

                var reader1 = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader1.Read()) // reader.Read tar första posten, i det här fallet är det bara en post
                {
                    Session["totalQuestions"] = Convert.ToInt32(reader1[0]); //0 = första kolumnen (det finns bara en = antalet frågor)
                    //Session["questionNumberCounter"] = Convert.ToInt32(reader1[0]);
                }

                var quesNum = ViewState["questionNumberCounter"].ToString();
                var quesTot = Session["totalQuestions"].ToString();

                lblQuestionNr.Text = quesNum + "/" + quesTot;


            }
```

//And on clicks:

```
 ViewState["questionNumberCounter"] = +1;
```

How do I get it to add +1 on click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ViewState["questionNumberCounter"]=Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["questionNumberCounter"])+1
```